# Constructive treatment of Jacobson rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

Which result is closest to the classical

**[General Hilbert's Nullstellensatz:](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/jacobson.pdf)** Finite type algebras over Jacobson rings are Jacobson.

and *constructively true* at the same time? And where can I find a proof of it?

I skimmed through the books by Lombardi/Quitté and Mines/Richman/Ruitenberg but there seems to be no discussion of Jacobson ring-related methods.

The usual definition of Jacobson rings relies heavily on prime ideals so perhaps one should find a suitable constructive version of the *definition* of a Jacobson ring first. I'm curious for your ideas.

Comment: Are these rings commutative?

Comment: Yes, they are. *dummy characters*

Comment: I'd be curious to know the meaning of "being constructively true at the same time". In particular, do you want something uniform in the ground Jacobson ring?

Comment: "one should find a suitable constructive version of the definition of a Jacobson ring first": Actually, there is one on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring): "In every quotient ring, the nilradical is equal to the Jacobson radical". The Jacobson radical has several equivalent constructive definitions (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57877/artin-jacobson-semisimple-rings-are-semisimple-constructively-too ).

Comment: @darijgrinberg You are right. However »every quotient ring« seems to be very strong, constructively. For example consider the statement that $ \mathbb{Z} $ is Jacobson. If $ I = \langle n \rangle$ is principal, then it is rather easy to prove that $ \operatorname{rad}(I) = \operatorname{Jac}(I) $. (Reduce to the case that $ n $ is prime and use that $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is a field. I think this should work intuitionistically.) If however $I$ is not assumed to be principal (or equivalently, finitely generated), I don't even know how to start.

Comment: @JakobWerner: True; maybe "every quotient ring by a finitely generated ideal".